# AngularJS reset prestine state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular form for inserting information through a resource service.

The service returns the inputted values as the model.  However, the form retains the validation information as though it isn't pristine and is dirty.

Is there a way to reset the pristine state of a form when the model changes?

(I don't and to reset the FORM, I want to reset the pristine state to match the model)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use : `myFormName.$setPristine()` after you set the model on the scope.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController

Comment: I added an reacquisition of the model in the success callback for the save.  In the success callback for the query call I called $setPristine() on the form.  It didn't wipe the form, but it didn't set itself as pristine either, all of the validations were still there.